# Spring code re-use

Tags: java, coding-style

I am new to Spring and would like to know how experienced Spring developers manage repeating code snippets.  One example that comes to mind is the following:

```
public String getSex() {
    // ISO 5218
    String gender;
    int sexvalue = Integer.parseInt(sex);
    switch (sexvalue) {
        case 0:
            gender = "Not known";
            break;
        case 1:
            gender = "Male";
            break;
        case 2:
            gender = "Female";
            break;
        case 9:
            gender = "Not applicable";
            break;
        default:
            gender = "Not known";
            break;
    }
    return gender;
}
```

I use this and other snippets in several classes.

I am also wondering how you mange, say, various collections that can be re-used.  A simple example would be the months of the year.

BTW, is there a more efficient way of coding this function?

Comment: A spring programmer would Copy/paste it into every class but use DI to inject it (best practice)

Comment: Is it best practice to consolidate such miscellaneous snippets in the one class?

Comment: Spring developers I know personally would use enum for this kind of task

Comment: @RobH: My comment was a joke, but yes it goes without saying that repeated code should be consolidated into a single function/class.

Comment: I did get the joke.  No one cuts and paste code these days do they?  I am going through a steep learning curve with Spring but it hasn't destroyed my sense of humour yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Spring-Specific, but I'd say this is a classic application for an [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
public Enum Gender{
    MALE, FEMALE
}

public enum Month{
    JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH /* etc. */; 
}
```